Код последней команды в Windows
Есть ли в Windows команда, которая вернёт код последней команды. На подобие echo $? в Linux?

Посмотрите ERRORLEVEL.

echo $ - это команда оболочки bash из Linux. Следовательно, вам нужно найти аналог какой-то командной оболочки из Windows. / Что именно вы используете в Винде? bat? PowerShell? / В принципе, в Винде тоже можно использовать, например, GitBash.

Если прямо в консоли, то там клавишей "вверх"

Ответом будет команда в cmd:
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
